# Next.JS using CSS Modules not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating my CRA to Next and having issues with locally scoped CSS modules.

#### File Tree

```sh
.
├── Headline.js
├── profile.png
└── welcome.module.css
```

#### Code

```
import React from 'react';
import "./welcome.module.css" 

function Headline() {
  return (
        <section className={'headliner-container'}>
          <div className={'main-headline'}></div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Headline;
```

I realize I can get this to work by doing `import styles from "./welcome.module.css"`  and referencing via `className={styles["classNameHere"]}`, but how does that scale for large migration projects? I want to use the CSS I had with minimal modification to my JSX.

## Update:

I found out I could add this and disable all the weird opinions Next is throwing into my CSS structure:

```
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }
})
```

Any opposition to this in my next config?

Comment: **CSS modules are supposed to be locally scoped and applied to their respective elements**. From the [docs](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#css-modules), they export an object of classes that need to be applied to an element. When you use `import "./welcome.module.css"`, then you're trying to make them global, which is anti-pattern. If you want global CSS, then you shouldn't use the `module` name, instead you should use: `import "./welcome.css"`.

Comment: is it possible to locally scope without needing to update every location in the JSX with a styles["... prefix?

Comment: No. But again, the module name specifies a CSS module. In your current CRA project, the classes are being treated as global classes.

Comment: Its a next not cra project...

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. Anyway, upon further testing, I noticed `import "./App.module.css";` doesn't even apply styles with the CRA: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/pkNJlvi.png). Only when importing and applying `styles` to the element does it work as expected: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/5zSxSYM.png). This further points to the fact that, if it's working with `.module.css` in your **CRA** project, then you're just using global classes and not local classes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into the same issue you had when I was migrating our UI component library. You might be able to do something like this. `import styles from "./welcome.module.css"`. This allows you to do minimum work on the CSS side while still be able to leverage CSS Modules down the road.

```
:global {
 .headliner-container {
   margin: 0 20px;
 }
}
```

I do suggest you at least use a component scope class name on the top-level DOM node if possible so CSS override will less likely to happen. I don't know how pure CSS Module might handle it since I used Less for my situation.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./welcome.module.css" 

function Headline() {
  return (
        <div className={styles.headLineWrapper}>
           <section className={'headliner-container'}>
             <div className={'main-headline'}></div>
           </section>
        </div> 
    );
}

export default Headline;
```

```css
/*LESS code */
.head-line-wrapper {
  :global {
   .headliner-container {
     margin: 0 20px;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate :) Pretty good answer, it diserves more upvotes :)

Comment: Hey there. I tried this and get the error `Selector ":global" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)` - for this to work do I need to use the `cssLoaderOptions` in next.config?

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me - will post an answer

Comment: EDIT: I had a slightly different use-case so won't paste an answer. The syntax I used in the module.css file to override a global CSS class was this `.override :global(.css-class-to-override) { /* rules */}`.  Then applying `styles.override` to the parent div's className did it.